# NodeJS - error while trying to install NPM module - installation error 401

Tags: node.js, npm, http-status-code-401

Tried to install parquet module with: `npm install parquets`

Getting error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: parquets@latest
```

Tried also: `sudo npm install parquets`. Got exact same error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: removing ~/.npmrc? did that help?

Comment: Are you behind some kind of corporate firewall? Using an on-prem package repository?

Comment: try to run your CLI under admin rights

Comment: This was proxy issue - behind corporate firewall..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo su -
```

then go the directory where you want to run npm install and

```
npm install
```